# Error in java method?

Tags: java

I have some simple java code to call a method with a value to calculate the volume. I just get error like missing ; in JCreator? What is wrong? This is new beginners non object programming level course. Therefore i guess there should be no public static in the method?

```
public class Matematik {

public static void main(String[] args) {

System.out.println(volym(10));

    double volym(int tal){

    return round((4 * math.pi * math.pow(tal,3) / 3),2);

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration for volym should not be in main:

```
public class Matematik {

    public static double volym(int tal){

        return round((4 * math.pi * math.pow(tal,3) / 3),2);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(volym(10));

    }
}
```

Edit: it's worth noting that you have other issues too.  Namely, java.lang.Math.PI (note the casing) and Math.pow.  And Math.round....

Comment: And it should not be `static`. Rather create a new object of type `Matematik` in `public static void main(...` and call its `volym` method there.

Comment: I see no reason to not make it static.  He said they haven't discussed objects, and it does not depend on any internal properties.

Comment: Thanks! That helped, but I still have some problems with the calculation with this line return Round((4 * Math.Pi * Math.pow(tal,3) / 3),2); I get an error: cannot find symbol ?

Comment: You likely need Math.Round.  Not sure what imports you have.  Also, see the note in Peter's post about round.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define a method inside a method.  This would be more obvious if you use the IDEs code formatting.  Move one of the `}` up to before the second method (BTW it must be static as well)

Also its `Math` not `math` and `Math.round` on take one value which it rounds to an integer.

If you want to round to two decimal places you can do

```
Math.round(x * 100) / 100.0;
```

Comment: Can't I use Math.Round(10.2321234,2) to get 10.23?

Comment: There is no `Math.Round` but you could make one if you wanted. There is a `Math.round` but it takes only one argument.  There is no point inventing methods unless you are writing them. ;)